# Add Font Awesome icon with label_tag

Tags: django, font-awesome, django-widget-tweaks

How do I add a Font Awesome icon like `<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>` to the following

`{{form.date.label_tag}}`

which uses widget_tweaks? I know generally you'd just do it like this

`<h2><span>Add<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span></h2>` but I haven't had any luck.

It just outputs the "Date added:"

[image: This is what the label looks like]

Comment: what's the output of `{{form.date.label_tag}}`? can you please show it?

Comment: @Lemayzeur added screenshot

Comment: I meant the html rendered

Comment: Basically, you just want a `plus sign` (+) right before the `label` *Date added*